# Run a Python script from PackageMaker in OSX

Tags: python, macos, packagemaker

I'm having a difficult time finding any decent documentation for packaging on OSX. My package needs to run a Python script that will do some launchd magic right after the app is installed. I tried using `-s scripts` with packagemaker and put my script in the directory `scripts`, but I had no luck. Is there something I'm missing? More importantly, where is all the packagemaker documentation? How can I get my Python script to run? The only thing I've seen [is this](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Stuff/PackageMaker_Howto.html), which is way outdated and doesn't cover the command line version.

I don't want to use the GUI; it makes my life too difficult.

Comment: It is very frustrating that the documentation for this utility is zero to non-existent, thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this issue.

1. The script needs to be named `postflight` and have a proper shebang line.
2. The script needs to exit with specific status codes (0 for success, which is the default, I believe).